# Who has green eyes and was/were killed by Arya?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In *Game of Thrones S08E03: The Long Night*, when Arya meets

> Melisandre

Arya says she was right that

> they would meet again & that she will shut many eyes forever, as in Season 3, Melisandre stated that Arya would shut brown eyes, green eyes, amongst others

Brown eyes are pretty common but do we know anyone with green eyes that Arya has shut forever?

Comment: As many Frey's as there were surely one of them had green eyes

Comment: @Skooba I am looking for named characters not unnamed frey soldier #34

Comment: Pretty sure blue eyes were the point of that exchange.

Comment: @MishaR yes, that was the most important main point but Melisandre would not make an off-handed comment unless she sees/interprets it in a vision. Interestingly, she mentioned all 3 colors in s03 itself & everything concerning Arya has come to pass

Comment: Cersei Lannister has green eyes.

Comment: Don't understand the 2 downvotes. Do you guys think Mel says stuff for kicks.

Comment: @KharoBangdo Don't pay attention to the downvotes. Some people gonna downvote. If it turns out the Arya ends up killing Cersei (I don't think so, but she *might*) you'll have the last laugh. Your question is good, don't sweat it.

Comment: Related: [Melisandre's Green Eye Prophecy for Arya](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/100041/49)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Petyr Baelish (in the books at least)

In the books, he is described:

> He had grown into a small man, an inch or two shorter than Catelyn, slender and quick, with the sharp features she remembered and the same **laughing grey-green eyes**.
>
> -- A Game of Thrones, Catelyn IV

However, Aidan Gillen, the actor who plays him on the show, has blue eyes.

---

Both Jamie and Cersei also have green eyes, but neither of them seem to have been killed yet. It's possible that she's talking the future as she tends to like to do.